# How do you disable the drag function on an ionic side menu?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

How do you disable the drag function on an ionic side menu? I am pretty new to this and need help. When I swipe right on the main page... it opens up a menu and I don't want this to happen. Here is my current code:

```
<!-- Side menu -->
<ion-side-menu side="left" drag-content="false">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
<h1 class="title">Cards</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content scroll="true">
</ion-side-menus>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.$root.canDrag = false;
```

Comment: You asked the same question before. Please remove it 1st. I suggest you also ask this question on Ionic Developer forum: http://forum.ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drag-content attribute must be written over  tag.

For e.g :

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">

      <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
           <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
               <h1 class="title">Cards</h1>
           </ion-header-bar>
           <ion-content scroll="true">
           </ion-content>
       </ion-pane> 

   </ion-side-menus>
```

This will do the job. !!

> Edit :

To Create a Menu Close Button, add the attribute **menu-toggle="menu_side"** to the button.

E.g

```
<button menu-toggle="right" class="button transparent button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) how do I open the menu from here?

Comment: Here is the button code I want the menu to open from:   <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleProjects()">
    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
  </button>

Comment: how to do it same using javascript?.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable drag side menu, for example on login page where you don't want side menu to be visible.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        '$log',
        '$ionicSideMenuDelegate',
        LoginFunction]);

function LoginFunction($scope, $log, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    var vm = this;

    $log.debug('its working');
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)
}
}());
```